# Let $S$ be the subgroup of $A$ such that $\psi(s,s')=0$ for all $s,s'\in S$ and $S$ is maximal with respect to this property.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, bilinear-form

> Let $A$ be a finite abelian group, and let
>
> $$ \psi : A \times A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} $$
>
> be an alternating, non-degenerate bilinear form on $A$.
>
> Let $S$ be the subgroup of $A$ such that $\psi(s,s')=0$ for all $s,s'\in S$ and $S$ is maximal with respect to this property.
>
> My question is, why can we take such $S$?

I think it is difficult to prove the existence of $S$ without constructing it concretely.

cf. This definition appears in  lemma 4 of this.

[https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0998-10.pdf](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/0998-10.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The word "the" here is incorrect--there is not necessarily a *unique* such subgroup $S$.  However, there does always exist some such subgroup.  Since $A$ is finite, you can just take a subgroup on which $\psi$ is zero of maximal cardinality.  (At least one such subgroup exists, namely the trivial subgroup.)

Comment: Do you mean that $S$ is not unique, but $\#S$ is unique?

Comment: In Lemma 4 of the linked article, the author deduces that $\#S^2 = \#A$. However, this seems strange to me because there is no a priori reason for both $S$ and $\#S$ to be uniquely determined by $A$ and $\psi$.

Comment: Yes, that is a nontrivial conclusion that is not at all obvious a priori.